# I need to read the memory by the string, but when I try it gives the following error

Tags: c++

```
argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
'int MessageBoxW(HWND,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,UINT)': unable to convert an argument 2 of 'char [255]' to 'LPCWSTR'
type conversion': conversion from 'unsigned int' to larger size 'LPVOID'
```

The code I'm using is this

```
char buffer[255] = { 0 };
            unsigned addr = 0xb50798;
            if (ReadProcessMemory(hproc, (LPVOID)addr, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL))
            {
                MessageBoxW(hwnd, buffer, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: `MessageBoxW` is the wide version, it takes an array of `wchar_t`, not `char`.

Comment: Use `MessageBoxA` if you really must.  Or convert the data to wide.  Assuming it's even a string....  Alternatively, encode it as a hexadecimal string.